# UIScrollView with multiple GLPaint's drawing view as subview ; Screen Capture

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, eaglview, eaglcontext

I have a `UIScrollView`, with multiple drawable views as subviews. I am using Apple's GLPaint code. My problem is when I capture the `UIScrollView's` content to form an `UIImage`, the state of my drawing view is not captured. Below is the code I use for capturing.

```
//this code captures the UIScrollView including the invisible part
-(UIImage*)captureImage {
    UIImage* image = nil;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_scrollView.contentSize);
    {
        CGPoint savedContentOffset = _scrollView.contentOffset;
        CGRect savedFrame = _scrollView.frame;

        _scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
        _scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, _scrollView.contentSize.width, _scrollView.contentSize.height);

        [_scrollView.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        _scrollView.contentOffset = savedContentOffset;
        _scrollView.frame = savedFrame;
    }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Can anyone help me with this problem please?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

you can add this function to your canvas class:

```
- (UIImage*)snapshot
{
    GLint backingWidth1, backingHeight1;

    // Bind the color renderbuffer used to render the OpenGL ES view
    // If your application only creates a single color renderbuffer which is already bound at this point,
    // this call is redundant, but it is needed if you're dealing with multiple renderbuffers.
    // Note, replace "_colorRenderbuffer" with the actual name of the renderbuffer object defined in your class.
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);

    // Get the size of the backing CAEAGLLayer
    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth1);
    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight1);

    NSInteger x = 0, y = 0, width = backingWidth1, height = backingHeight1;
    NSInteger dataLength = width * height * 4;
    GLubyte *data = (GLubyte*)malloc(dataLength * sizeof(GLubyte));

    // Read pixel data from the framebuffer
    glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
    glReadPixels(x, y, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    // Create a CGImage with the pixel data
    // If your OpenGL ES content is opaque, use kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast to ignore the alpha channel
    // otherwise, use kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast
    CGDataProviderRef ref = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, data, dataLength, NULL);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGImageRef iref = CGImageCreate(width, height, 8, 32, width * 4, colorspace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big | kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast,
                                    ref, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

    // OpenGL ES measures data in PIXELS
    // Create a graphics context with the target size measured in POINTS
    NSInteger widthInPoints, heightInPoints;
    if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions) {
        // On iOS 4 and later, use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to take the scale into consideration
        // Set the scale parameter to your OpenGL ES view's contentScaleFactor
        // so that you get a high-resolution snapshot when its value is greater than 1.0
        CGFloat scale = self.contentScaleFactor;
        widthInPoints = width / scale;
        heightInPoints = height / scale;
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(widthInPoints, heightInPoints), NO, scale);
    }
    else {
        // On iOS prior to 4, fall back to use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext
        widthInPoints = width;
        heightInPoints = height;
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(widthInPoints, heightInPoints));
    }

    CGContextRef cgcontext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // UIKit coordinate system is upside down to GL/Quartz coordinate system
    // Flip the CGImage by rendering it to the flipped bitmap context
    // The size of the destination area is measured in POINTS
    CGContextSetBlendMode(cgcontext, kCGBlendModeCopy);
    CGContextDrawImage(cgcontext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, widthInPoints, heightInPoints), iref);

    // Retrieve the UIImage from the current context
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // Clean up
    free(data);
    CFRelease(ref);
    CFRelease(colorspace);
    CGImageRelease(iref);

    return image;
}
```

and invoke it from the scrollview